# How to compute hash of a large file chunk?

Tags: c#, file, hash, filestream

I want to be able to compute the hashes of arbitrarily sized file chunks of a file in C#.

eg: Compute the hash of the 3rd gigabyte in 4gb file.

The main problem is that I don't want to load the entire file at memory, as there could be several files and the offsets could be quite arbitrary.

AFAIK, the HashAlgorithm.ComputeHash allows me to either use a byte buffer, of a stream. The stream would allow me to compute the hash efficiently, but for the entire file, not just for a specific chunk.

I was thinking to create aan alternate FileStream object and pass it to ComputeHash, where I would overload the FileStream methods and have read only for a certain chunk in a file.

Is there a better solution than this, preferably using the built in C# libraries ?
Thanks.

Comment: You could use `TransformBlock` and `TransformFinalBlock`

Comment: but that works only for a byte array ? The reason I wanted to use streams because it doesn't require having the entire chunk or file in memory to compute the hash.

Comment: `ComputeHash(stream)` reads it in pieces, calls `TransformBlock` on each piece, and `TransformFinalBlock` in the end. You don't need 1GB array just because you want to hash a 1GB block.

Comment: Yes but it will read starting from the beginning until the end of the stream ? I want it to read from a specific position in the stream until another position or after a certain count. I don't want it to keep hashing until the end of the stream.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `TransformBlock` and `TransformFinalBlock` directly. That's pretty similar to what `HashAlgorithm.ComputeHash` does internally.

Something like:

```
using(var hashAlgorithm = new SHA256Managed())
using(var fileStream = new File.OpenRead(...))
{     
    fileStream.Position = ...;
    long bytesToHash = ...;

    var buf = new byte[4 * 1024];
    while(bytesToHash > 0)
    {
        var bytesRead = fileStream.Read(buf, 0, (int)Math.Min(bytesToHash, buf.Length));
        hashAlgorithm.TransformBlock(buf, 0, bytesRead, null, 0);
        bytesToHash -= bytesRead;
        if(bytesRead == 0)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Unexpected end of stream");
    }
    hashAlgorithm.TransformFinalBlock(buf, 0, 0);
    var hash = hashAlgorithm.Hash;
    return hash;
};
```

Answer (score 4):

You should pass in either:

- A byte array containing the chunk of data to compute the hash from
- A stream that restricts access to the chunk you want to computer the hash from

The second option isn't all that hard, here's a quick [LINQPad](http://linqpad.net) program I threw together. Note that it lacks quite a bit of error handling, such as checking that the chunk is actually available (ie. that you're passing in a position and length of the stream that actually exists and doesn't fall off the end of the underlying stream).

Needless to say, if this should end up as production code I would add a lot of error handling, and write a bunch of unit-tests to ensure all edge-cases are handled correctly.

You would construct the `PartialStream` instance for your file like this:

```
const long gb = 1024 * 1024 * 1024;
using (var fileStream = new FileStream(@"d:\temp\too_long_file.bin", FileMode.Open))
using (var chunk = new PartialStream(fileStream, 2 * gb, 1 * gb))
{
    var hash = hashAlgorithm.ComputeHash(chunk);
}
```

Here's the [LINQPad](http://linqpad.net) test program:

```
void Main()
{
    var buffer = Enumerable.Range(0, 256).Select(i => (byte)i).ToArray();
    using (var underlying = new MemoryStream(buffer))
    using (var partialStream = new PartialStream(underlying, 64, 32))
    {
        var temp = new byte[1024]; // too much, ensure we don't read past window end
        partialStream.Read(temp, 0, temp.Length);
        temp.Dump();
        // should output 64-95 and then 0's for the rest (64-95 = 32 bytes)
    }
}

public class PartialStream : Stream
{
    private readonly Stream _UnderlyingStream;
    private readonly long _Position;
    private readonly long _Length;

    public PartialStream(Stream underlyingStream, long position, long length)
    {
        if (!underlyingStream.CanRead || !underlyingStream.CanSeek)
            throw new ArgumentException("underlyingStream");

        _UnderlyingStream = underlyingStream;
        _Position = position;
        _Length = length;
        _UnderlyingStream.Position = position;
    }

    public override bool CanRead
    {
        get
        {
            return _UnderlyingStream.CanRead;
        }
    }

    public override bool CanWrite
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public override bool CanSeek
    {
        get
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    public override long Length
    {
        get
        {
            return _Length;
        }
    }

    public override long Position
    {
        get
        {
            return _UnderlyingStream.Position - _Position;
        }

        set
        {
            _UnderlyingStream.Position = value + _Position;
        }
    }

    public override void Flush()
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }

    public override long Seek(long offset, SeekOrigin origin)
    {
        switch (origin)
        {
            case SeekOrigin.Begin:
                return _UnderlyingStream.Seek(_Position + offset, SeekOrigin.Begin) - _Position;

            case SeekOrigin.End:
                return _UnderlyingStream.Seek(_Length + offset, SeekOrigin.Begin) - _Position;

            case SeekOrigin.Current:
                return _UnderlyingStream.Seek(offset, SeekOrigin.Current) - _Position;

            default:
                throw new ArgumentException("origin");
        }
    }

    public override void SetLength(long length)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }

    public override int Read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        long left = _Length - Position;
        if (left < count)
            count = (int)left;
        return _UnderlyingStream.Read(buffer, offset, count);
    }

    public override void Write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your suggestion - passing in a restricted access wrapper for your `FileStream` - is the cleanest solution. Your wrapper should defer everything to the wrapped `Stream` *except* the `Length` and `Position` properties.

How? Simply create a class that inherits from `Stream`. Make the constructor take:

- Your source `Stream` (in your case, a `FileStream`)
- The chunk start position
- The chunk end position

As an extension - this is a list of all the `Streams` that are available http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream%28v=vs.100%29.aspx#inheritanceContinued

Comment: Actually, you also need to add a few controls in the Read method, otherwise you could read past the end of the "substream".

Answer (score 1):

To easily compute the hash of a chunk of a larger stream, use these two methods:

- [HashAlgorithm.TransformBlock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.hashalgorithm.transformblock%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
- [HashAlgorithm.TransformFinalBlock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.hashalgorithm.transformfinalblock%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Here's a [LINQPad](http://linqpad.net) program that demonstrates:

```
void Main()
{
    const long gb = 1024 * 1024 * 1024;
    using (var stream = new FileStream(@"d:\temp\largefile.bin", FileMode.Open))
    {
        stream.Position = 2 * gb; // 3rd gb-chunk
        byte[] buffer = new byte[32768];
        long amount = 1 * gb;

        using (var hashAlgorithm = SHA1.Create())
        {
            while (amount > 0)
            {
                int bytesRead = stream.Read(buffer, 0,
                    (int)Math.Min(buffer.Length, amount));

                if (bytesRead > 0)
                {
                    amount -= bytesRead;
                    if (amount > 0)
                        hashAlgorithm.TransformBlock(buffer, 0, bytesRead,
                            buffer, 0);
                    else
                        hashAlgorithm.TransformFinalBlock(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                }
                else
                    throw new InvalidOperationException();
            }
            hashAlgorithm.Hash.Dump();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer your original question (*"Is there a better solution..."*):

**Not that I know of.**

This seems to be a very special, non-trivial task, so a little extra work might be involved anyway. I think your approach of using a custom *Stream*-class goes in the right direction, I'd probably do exactly the same.

And *Gusdor* and *xander* have already provided very helpful information on how to implement that — good job guys!